# Assign id to EditText programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageButton and when the user clicks on it an EditText is added to the layout. So what I want is that each EditText has a unique id.

```
a = 0;
imgAddText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if (a <= 5) {
           layoutAddText.addView(createEditText());
           a++;
       }
    }
});

private EditText createEditText() {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
        return editText;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are returning the same editText in createEditText(). Try to change it to "new EditText()" or inflate from xml.

Comment: Sorry I happened to delete the line while writing the question.

Answer (score 1):

actually all view have `setId` method. You can make use of it.

```
setId(int id)
```

i would strong suggest you use `setTag` instead. I hope reason being your setting id is using same id to get it back by `findViewId(int)`. Same thing you can achieve by    `findViewWithTag(Object tag)`

Comment: When user clicks on button an ediitext is created. I want each edittext to have a unique id not the same.

Comment: I think depending on the use case, this answer is the most appropriate.

Comment: all the ids which are android generated will be long values and huge number. You can have for loop or your own unique number generation logic and set to edit text.

Comment: actually i know how to assign an id programatically but i am not able to figure out how to assign unique id to each newly created view.

Comment: oh.. well you can start from 1000 as example, then later more edittexts you wants to add just increase number by one.. like 1001,1002

Comment: I was about to ask if i will be able to assign a number as id. I'll give it a try. @sush

Comment: yes you can.. i have worked on that part.. it works

Answer (score 0):

In createEditText() method try this

```
    EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    editText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    editText.setId(R.id.edit);
    return editText;
```

Comment: i want each edittext to have a unique id not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting tag instead of id as:

```
editText.setTag(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

or generate a unique id by creating a class say `IdGenerator` like:

```
public class IdGenerator() {
    private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);
    public static int generateViewId() {
        for (; ; ) {
            final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
            int newValue = result + 1;
            if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1;
            if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then do :

```
editText.setId(IdGenerator.generateViewId());
```